# Using a gmail oath2 token to access web email

Tags: oauth, gmail, keychain, password-reset, oauth2

I forgot my password to an old gmail account. I have tried the regular route of going through gmail password recovery: answering questions, it keeps looping back to the questions, so I think I'm getting them wrong, using mobile phone recovery is out of question - I have moved to a different country and my old phone number is inactive, and the recovery email address is from a university account that has been disabled.

The thing is I still have access to the account through a Mac Mail program. I can receive emails from it, and also through my iphone. The logical place to look, the keychain, doesn't have the password listed, it just shows an empty field for the password.

What I do have in the keychain is this:
[image: Gmail entries in keychain]

My hunch is that the Mail program is using oath2 tokens to access my gmail. My question is, can I use this token for a web browser, like Chrome, to login to my account and make changes? I need to make changes to my scholar account and other changes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the oath2 token used by applications for login via the web browser